# Python multiprocess loop

Tags: python, loops, multiprocessing

Im doing MCMC calculations using PyMC.
My data consists of 47 parts each with a shape of 24 * 1000.

In order for MCMC to work I created a large array out of the 47 parts so do I have now a (1128)* 1000 array.

The model that is fitted then creates a same size array.
It does that in a loop since for each of the 47 parts there are differing values that have to be loaded (like scaling factors).

Lets say map is my array:

```
for i in range(len(map[::])/47):

  scale = scale_all[i]

  self.trans_calc["t"] = 0.   
  self.trans_calc.xyzPos()
  pos0 = self.trans_calc.calc_pos1()

  for k in range(24):

    self.trans_calc["t"] = self.time[k]               
    self.trans_calc.xyzPos()

    if self.trans_calc.onstar() == False: 

        curve = pos0

    else:

        pos1 = self.trans_calc.calc_pos1()
        curve = pos0 - pos1 + 1.0 * scale

    map[k+i*47] = curve

return map
```

Since the 47 parts are independent of each other I would get a speedup if I would use multiprocessing.

I just dont understand how I have to set it up in order to be able to write to the correct possition in map.
I have searched for a solution but not found something. Or I did not understand what I found.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with PyMC and it is hard for me to see what exactly you are doing in the code. But if the processes are independent, you should write your script in a way that you can 'map' every piece of the chain on a function which returns the result.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=8)              
result = pool.map(build_markov_chain, list_of_input_arrays)
```

In this way the results are in the same order as the input. So instead of building a (1128)*1000 array I would suggest keeping them as a list containing 47 arrays with shape 24*1000.

Comment: In order for Markov to work everything has to be calculated in one step. Thats why I create this large array. The code example just shows how the model array is created using loops which is kind of slow. The Markov has some free parameters which influence the model array in each step. So each Markov step the array will be created anew and compared to the experiental data. The data consists of 47 parts. Each has 24 subparts. Subpart 1 of part 1 has the same time information as subpart 1 of part 2 (there was an error in the k loop I corrected it).

Comment: Ok I got a great speed up through doing the following: I am using cython to create an extra program that does the looping. Just pasting the pyhon code did give me a over faktor two speedup.

Comment: Ok, seems like you are on the way of solving your own problem. :-)